# Query sin repetir datos

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

Tengo el siguiente query de dos tablas, el problema es que solo necesito mostrar el primer registro por CODIGO, no puedo utilizar TOP 1 porque necesito ver todos los codigos, solo el primer registro de cada codigo

```html
 select P.CODIGO, P.SEMANA, S.FECHA
 from PERSONAS P
 Left join SEMANAS S 
 on P.SEMANA= S.SEMANA 
 group by P.CODIGO, P.SEMANA, S.FECHA
 ORDER BY S.FECHA
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```html
 
PERSONAS
CODIGO INT
SEMANA INT

SEMANAS
SEMANA INT
FECHA  DATE
```

espero haberme dado a entender
Gracias

Comment: Por favor agregue información de prueba de las tablas a usar en esta consulta.

Comment: ¿Que versión de SQL Server?

Comment: @PatricioMoracho 2014 porque?

Comment: Porque de acuerdo a la versión se pueden implementar distintas soluciones

Comment: @PatricioMoracho como cual?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
;WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT P.CODIGO, 
           P.SEMANA, 
           S.FECHA,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY P.CODIGO ORDER BY S.FECHA) AS RN
           FROM PERSONAS P
           LEFT JOIN SEMANAS S 
                ON P.SEMANA= S.SEMANA 
           GROUP BY P.CODIGO, P.SEMANA, S.FECHA
)
SELECT *
       FROM CTE
       WHERE RN = 1
```

#### Detalle:

- Usamos un [CTE](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) para definir la consulta principal
- En esta establecemos un numerador mediante [`ROW_NUMBER()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#a-using-the-over-clause-with-the-row_number-function) el cual se reiniciará por cada `P.CODIGO` y estará ordenado por `S.FECHA`
- Con lo anterior podremos ahora sía obtener solo las filas que se correspondan con la primera de cada código

Comment: Muchas gracias !